# Getting Json data using TCP socket

Tags: android, tcp

I've a connection with TCP socket, it gets connected perfectly, after that if i send a message to server then it sends back to me response as a JSON data, but in JSON there is a null character at the end...I'm trying to read whole line of the JSON response.

This is what I've done to read

```
 while (mRun) {
    mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

    if (mServerMessage != null) {

    // mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);

    Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

  }
    if (mServerMessage == null) {

    mRun = false;

   // mMessageListener.messageReceived("disconnected");

Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "disconnected");

   }
  //mServerMessage = null;

   }
```

But i want to read each character until i get null and append it to a string so that i can get the response faster. I've tried with 'mBufferIn.readLine()', it always gives me the response after a long time....can anyone please suggest some solutions for this, I've got stuck in it!